Zebra ZQ520 is not printing through code or Setup Utilities
I have an issue like that when I send ZPL commands through c# code to the printer via Bluetooth it prints blank label (after calibration) or sometimes only a peace of the expected text. Additionally, sometimes it prints on 2 labels even if I set gap in 'sense_mode'.
The same situation is through Zebra Setup Utilities. I checked my ZPL code on https://labelary.com/ and it looks normal. So I think it is not the fault of my code. My commands look like this:




! Ul setvar "device.languages" "zpl"



! Ul setvar "media.type" "label"



! Ul setvar "media.sense_mode" "gap"



~jc^xa^jus^xz



^XA^F050BY2^B3N,N,100,Y,N^FD33444222^FS^XZ

But the configuration info (by pressing the feed button while turning on) prints fine (it looks normal).
Regards.
I checked my ZPL code on https://labelary.com/ and it looks normal.
The configuration info (by pressing the feed button while turning on) prints fine.

After firmware update still I have the same problem.

How do you send the ZPL code, maybe it's an encoding problem?

@DelphiCoder
Thanks for response. I found the reason for the issue. There was a problem with labels roll, but I don't know exactly what was wrong with it. I set a new labels roll and it started to work correctly. I checked the old one again and there was the issue. Perhaps the gap sensor wasn't stick to the label and it didn't notice gaps and generally label.

I found the reason for the issue. There was a problem with labels roll, but I don't know exactly what was wrong with it. I set a new labels roll and it started to work correctly. I checked the old one again and there was the issue. Perhaps the gap sensor wasn't stick to the label and it didn't notice gaps and generally label.
